# How can lock array of records for adding and deleting element in thread

Tags: arrays, multithreading, delphi

I want to get some query from server time by time and list this URL query on the array of records.

For freeing of memory must free the elements of an array that procced.
This process is on the thread to prevent freezing of App.
If the array is not locked, maybe deleting of element rise exception because that other element is in process or adding or deleting an index of element changed.

My question is: ’How can I lock an array of records for adding and deleting an element in the thread?’

This sample code is simplified for understanding my actual App code:

```
uses  IdHTTP;

type 
  tMyRecAra=record
    sta:integer;
    url:string;
    // ...
    // ...
  end;

var MyRecAra: array of tMyRecAra;

procedure TfoTestAra.btAddClick(Sender: TObject);
var cou:integer;
begin
  //+ start lock array MyRecAra ?
    cou:=length(MyRecAra);
    SetLength(MyRecAra, length(MyRecAra)+1);
    MyRecAra[cou].sta:=0;
    MyRecAra[cou].url:='http:/......';
  //- stop lock array MyRecAra ?    
end;

procedure TfoTestAra.btStartClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  IdHTTP1:TIdHTTP;
  mainThr,curThr : TThread;
  cStream:TMemoryStream;
begin
  mainThr := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
      begin
        while true {or other condition}  do
          begin
            curThr := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
              procedure
              var i:integer;
              begin
                //+ start lock array MyRecAra ?
                  for i := 0 to (length(MyRecAra)-1) do
                    begin
                      if (MyRecAra[i].sta=0) then
                        begin
                          MyRecAra[i].sta:=1;
                          //...
                          //..
                           {for example : IdHTTP1.Get(MyRecAra[i].url,cStream)};
                          //...
                          //..
                        end;
                      end;
                //- stop lock array MyRecAra ?
              end);
            curThr.Start;
            sleep(5000);
          end;
      end);
  mainThr.start;
end;

procedure TfoTestAra.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var 
  sumFee:integer;
  i, j:integer;
begin
  // timer.interval=10000;

  //+ start lock array MyRecAra?
    sumFee:=0;
    for i := 0 to (length(MyRecAra)-1) do
    begin
      if (MyRecAra[i].sta=1) then
        begin
          inc(sumFee);
          for j := (i+1) to  sumFee-1 do
            begin
              if  (MyRecAra[j].sta <> 1) then
                MyRecAra[i]:=MyRecAra[j]
            end;

        end;
      end;
      if sumFee<>0 then
        SetLength(MyRecAra, (length(MyRecAra)-sumFee));
   //+ stop lock array MyRecAra ?
end;

End.
```

Comment: @Dalija Prasnikar. your solution was useful for others that need lock and unlock memory from change and it works perfectly on my simple code , but my main code is very complex  and apply this method need a lot of  change on it. please append again your answer for learning propose for others.

Comment: You should ask another question then, when you are ready. One thing that definitely does not look right here is doing cleanup on a Timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lock to protect access to shared data and then general pattern in all places where you access the data would be:

```
Lock.Enter;
try
  // procected code
finally
  Lock.Leave;
end;
```

You need to declare lock variable in the same scope as the data that needs protection and you need to initialize that lock before it is used for the first time and free it when it is no longer needed.

For instance, if your `MyRecAra` is global data in unit, then `Lock` also needs to be global and initialized in initialization section of the unit and released in finalization section.

If `MyRecAra` is field in form or some other class, then `Lock` would also be a field in that class, initialized in constructor and released in destructor.

Commonly used lock is `TCriticalSection`. There are other types of locks, but for start this one will do just fine.

```
var
  Lock: TCriticalSection;
  MyRecAra: TMyRecAra; 

initialization

  Lock := TCriticalSection.Create;

finalization

  Lock.Free;

end.
```

Comment: Thanks. I add your approach to my sample code and it is works fine, but when I add this manner to main code, my App  hang up  and  when trace it, I saw 'lock.enter' occurred many time inside of the thread and then 'lock.leave' occurs one after one and finally trace stop on one of the 'lock.enter' lines . mention that I enclose all my code with this structure: 'try....lock.enter...finally...lock.leave...end'

Comment: The `Enter` needs to be *before* the `try`, as shown in Dalija's answer. Make sure you have a corresponding `Leave` for *every* successful `Enter`.

Comment: Besides what Remy said, you have template for using locks, but that does not mean you will get an easy ride. You are requesting lock from both background thread and main thread. If you hold a lock for a long time in the background thread, then main thread will be frozen until it manages to acquire the lock and vice versa. There are different ways to solve such issues but solutions depend a lot on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: like a stoical network App(e.g. WhatsApp), I want request query from database on server, base of http protocol and after receiving a result from server proceed to analyzing  of received data and affect my app base of that result. This requests save to an array and then proceed one by one. Your solution is very useful but on my App with a lot of straggling and apply your advice(prevent nested thread and use of right try...finally...end ), I can't prevent hang on my app.

Comment: You need to change your complete code logic then. But there are too many unknowns about what you are doing to give you precise answer on how to approach it. For instance, what are you doing in timer - are you refreshing data, if so then this is wrong approach, you should signal refresh not on timer, but from the background thread when you actually have new data ready. Do you need to keep array locked while you are retrieving results from the server. Better option would be to retrieve result in some temporary storage and only lock array while you are adding new data.

Comment: Also there is not information on what you are actually storing in your array. Very likely you store too much there - in other words you need to split data in that array to multiple arrays. One array (list) for data that needs to be retrieved, one that will store retrieved results. And then you will have different locks for different arrays and that can prevent extensive locking... Again, those are just possible solutions because there is not enough information about exact problem and whole workflow.

Comment: I store on  'MyHttpCommandArray', requested query from server (for example: query that  fetch new message stored to server  for current client that received on server) and result stream convert to  data structure  and save to local user  database  and then proceed to showing on forms. My Code split to this section . 1- add new request to array. 2- find a 'NotProceed' record. 3-mark this record to OnProgress 4-send http request to server (on thread).

Comment: 5-recive result stream and convert result to data structure and save to local dbf and mark record array state to 'Passed'. 6-update screen data by affected data. 7-on interval time delete 'Passed' recorded for freeing memory.